# How to watch one gulp file that imports other?

Tags: css, gulp

My sass structure look like this.

```
    - /base
    -- _fonts.scss
    -- _all.scss
    - /components
    -- _all.scss
    -- _header.scss
    -- _footer.scss
    - main.scss
```

Each _all.scss imports all files in the current folder, then the main.scss imports all _all files from each folder.

The problem I am facing is that I actually need to save main.scss in order for gulp to generate the .css file. If i watch all files it will then generate a lot of .css files which I don't need.

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/stylesheets/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
  gulp.watch('./src/stylesheets/main.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

How do I make gulp watch all files and generate only one css file in the public folder?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it.

**Main.scss**

```
@import "your/relative/path/of/your/_partial-file1";
@import "your/relative/path/of/your/_partial-file2";

/*Other scss stylings if needed*/
```

**In your gulpfile.js, add the sass task**

```
gulp.task('css', ()=>{

 return gulp.src('src/scss/*.scss') //target all the .css files in the specified directory

   .pipe(sass()) //gulp-sass module to convert scss files into css file

   .pipe(minifyCSS()) //method to minify the final css file

   .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css')); //outputs final css file into the specified directory

   console.log('CSS build');

});



gulp.task('default', [ 'css','your', 'other','tasks' ],()=>{

console.log("All done. Watching files...");



 //watch the files in the specified directory.

 //if any changes are made to the files, the specified task will be executed in the watch method

gulp.watch('src/**/*.scss',['css']);

});
```

Find the full article here: http://todarman.com/gulp-configuration-build-html-css-js/

Hope this helps.